# Why does adding the Perl /x switch stop my regex from matching?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match:

```
JOB: fruit 342 apples to get
```

The code matches:

```
$line =~ /^JOB: fruit (\d+) apples to get/
```

But, when I add the `/x` switch in:

```
$line =~ /^JOB: fruit (\d+) apples to get/x
```

It does not match.

I looked into the `/x` switch, and it says it just lets you do comments.  I don't know why adding `/x` stops my regex from matching.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `/x` modifier tells Perl to ignore most whitespace that isn't escaped in the regex.

For example, let's just focus on `apples to get`. You could match it with:

```
$line =~ /apples to get/
```

But if you try:

```
$line =~ /apples to get/x
```

then Perl will ignore the spaces. So it would be like trying to match `applestoget`.

You can read more about it in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#/x). They have this nice example of how you can use the modifier to make the code more readable.

```
 # Delete (most) C comments.
$program =~ s {
        /\* # Match the opening delimiter.
        .*? # Match a minimal number of characters.
        \*/ # Match the closing delimiter.
} []gsx;
```

They also mention how to match whitespace or `#` again while using the `/x` modifier.

> Use of /x means that if you want real whitespace or # characters in
>   the pattern (outside a bracketed character class, which is unaffected
>   by /x), then you'll either have to escape them (using backslashes or
>   \Q...\E ) or encode them using octal, hex, or \N{} escapes.

Answer (score 4):

Part of allowing comments is also ignoring literal white space.  Use `\s` or `[ ]` for spaces you wish to match.

For example

```
$line =~ /^                      #beginning of string
           JOB:[ ]fruit[ ]       #some literal text 
           (\d+)                 #capture digits to $1
           [ ]apples[ ]to[ ]get  #more literal text
         /x
```

Notice all those spaces before the beginning of the comments.  It would stink if they counted....